# WordPress Custom Post Types with own lists

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I have in my theme a custom post type called "recipes". I can add text, a thumbnail and add categories. I want to add a ingredients list to this post type. I need a global list of ingredients which I can use for a single recipe. How can i create a global list for the custom post type like categories but just for ingredients?

Here's my code for the post type:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'my_recipes' );
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'my_recipes_messages' );
add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_recipes_help' );

function my_recipes() {
$labels = array(
'name'               => 'Recipes',
'singular_name'      => 'Recipe',
'menu_name'          => 'Recipes',
'name_admin_bar'     => 'Recipe',
'add_new'            => 'Add New',
'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Recipe',
'new_item'           => 'New Recipe',
'edit_item'          => 'Edit Recipe',
'view_item'          => 'View Recipe',
'all_items'          => 'All Recipes',
'search_items'       => 'Search Recipes',
'parent_item_colon'  => 'Parent Recipes:',
'not_found'          => 'No recipes found.',
'not_found_in_trash' => 'No recipes found in Trash.'
);

$args = array(
'labels'        => $labels,
'public'        => true,
'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'recipe' ),
'has_archive'   => true,
'menu_position' => 20,
'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-carrot',
'taxonomies'        => array( 'post_tag', 'category' ),
'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt')
);
register_post_type( 'my_recipe', $args );
}

function my_recipes_messages( $messages ) {
$post = get_post();

$messages['recipe'] = array(
0  => '',
1  => 'Recipe updated.',
2  => 'Custom field updated.',
3  => 'Custom field deleted.',
4  => 'Recipe updated.',
5  => isset( $_GET['revision'] ) ? sprintf( 'Recipe restored to revision from %s',wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false,
6  => 'Recipe published.',
7  => 'Recipe saved.',
8  => 'Recipe submitted.',
9  => sprintf(
'Recipe scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>.',
date_i18n( 'M j, Y @ G:i', strtotime( $post->post_date ) )
),
10 => 'Recipe draft updated.'
);

return $messages;
}

function my_recipes_help() {

$screen = get_current_screen();

if ( 'recipe' != $screen->post_type ) {
return;
}

$basics = array(
'id'      => 'recipe_basics',
'title'   => 'Recipe Basics',
'content' => 'Content for help tab here'
);

$formatting = array(
'id'      => 'recipe_formatting',
'title'   => 'Recipe Formatting',
'content' => 'Content for help tab here'
);

$screen->add_help_tab( $basics );
$screen->add_help_tab( $formatting );

}
```

Comment: There are a couple of wonderful free plugins out there that give you more granular control of fields. I would recommend looking into one of those, such as [ACF}(https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). For instance, I would possibly use a [repeater](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/) with either a select list for one field, or possibly an entire taxonomy or CPT for the ingredient.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to have a global list of ingredients that you can add, as you mentioned, like categories or tags, then you're looking for a custom taxonomy.

Try this tool:
https://generatewp.com/taxonomy/

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpfull! Is there any option that i can add the amount for the ingredient to the recipe? For example: Milk = 100 ml Milk?

Comment: For that you would be better off using ACF, as @chris-haas mentioned. You would want to create a Repeater field with two sub-fields - one text field for the amount, and one with all the ingredients in a select field.